# Is it possible to use SELECT after WHERE

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables: 1 master table and 1 that I'm trying to put together.

- `TABLE1`: ID (AUTOINCREMENT) NAME PARENT
- `TABLE2`: ID(AUTOINCREMENT) PARENT CHILD

SQL code:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (PARENT, CHILD) 
   SELECT TABLE1.PARENT, TABLE1.ID 
   FROM TABLE1
   WHERE TABLE1.PARENT = (SELECT DISTINCT TABLE1.PARENT FROM TABLE1)
```

So I want my query to go over all the PARENTs and one by one get all its children.

Obviously it's not working and it is returning only the first PARENT and its children IDs

Comment: Wait your WHERE statement, doesn't make sense, its of course always true.

Comment: Because my use of = makes it that way using IN like @Cheloideman said would solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query would produce the exact same results as the much simpler:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (PARENT, CHILD)
SELECT PARENT, ID
FROM TABLE1
```

The subquery in the where clause has no effect.  It's basically saying, please insert parent and id from table 1 where parent and id are in table 1.  They will all be.

Now if you were using a separate table in the subquery this might make sense.  But even then I would suggest simply joining like so:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (PARENT, CHILD) 
SELECT TABLE1.PARENT, TABLE1.ID 
FROM TABLE1
JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT PARENT FROM TABLE2) TABLE2
ON TABLE1.PARENT = TABLE2.PARENT
```

Comment: Giving it a try. OH! that makes perfect sense. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, using `IN` instead of `=`.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (PARENT, CHILD) 
SELECT TABLE1.PARENT, TABLE1.ID 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TABLE1.PARENT IN (SELECT DISTINCT TABLE1.PARENT FROM  TABLE1)
```

Comment: Awesome! worked. Will mark it in 10 minutes :) Thanks